# Button Dropdown Feature

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
    <style>
        .custom-box {
            background-color: #ff5733;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .box-title {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .box-content {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #333;
        }

        .custom-button {
            background-color: #ff8f33;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .custom-button:hover {
            background-color: #ff5722;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            margin: 10px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-box">
        <div class="box-title">Dropdown Menu</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            Sample Text
        </div>
        <button class="custom-button" id="dropdown-button">Click Me</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Text</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Sample Text</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Sample Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const dropdownButton = document.getElementById('dropdown-button');
        const dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu');

        dropdownButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            dropdownMenu.style.display = dropdownMenu.style.display === 'none' ? 'flex' : 'none';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, the "Not Dropdown Text" represents any text which doesn't have dropdown capabilities; however, "Dropdown Text" refers to a text that can be further expanded to show hidden text.

How can I achieve the dropdown within this dropdown box? When I click the text that has further dropdown capabilities, it should display hidden text inside the box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution is to have a list within your list that has more data.

I also changed the click handler for the panel itself to the title. This way you can click the elements within the body to open/close.

```js
document.querySelector('.tile-label')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    const _parent = this.parentNode;
    _parent.classList.toggle('expanded');
    const plus = _parent.querySelector('.plus');
    plus.style.transform = _parent.classList.contains('expanded') ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)';
  });

const toggleChild = (e) => {

  if (e.currentTarget == e.target) {
    const el = e.target;
    el.classList.toggle("active")
  }
}

const level2 = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden-text ul li:has(ul)");

level2.forEach((li) => li.addEventListener("click", toggleChild))
```

```css
.tile-container {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rectangle {
  background-color: #0051a5;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1em;
  grid-template-areas: "sample plus" "extratext extratext";
}

.plus {
  grid-area: plus;
  background: linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), #fff;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 60% 2.5px, 2.5px 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.radius {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.tile-label {
  grid-area: sample;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 1em;
  height: 2em;
}

.tile-accent {
  color: #FFC72C;
}

.hidden-text {
  grid-area: extratext;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  margin: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.expanded>.hidden-text {
  display: block;
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/*Hides the child list be default*/

.hidden-text ul li ul {
  display: none;
}


/*active class toggles the visibility of the sub elements*/

.hidden-text ul li.active ul{
  display: block;
}

li .plus{
  transform:rotate(0);
}

li.active .plus{
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

/*changes the cursor to a pointer for the list items that have a child ul*/

.hidden-text ul li:has(ul) .plus {
  float:right
}

.hidden-text ul li:has(ul) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tile-container">
    <div class="rectangle">
      <div class="plus radius"></div>
      <div class="tile-label">
        Sample <span class="tile-accent">Text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-text">
        <ul>
          <li>Not Dropdown Text</li>
          <li>Dropdown Text <div class="plus radius"></div>
            <ul>
              <li>More Text!!</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Not Dropdown Text</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah I see, also it gives an uncaught typeerror: cannot read properties of null (reading classList) error when I run the code

Comment: also is it possible to add like a dropdown symbol or anything to make it clear that its a dropdown text?

Answer (score -1):

To get a dropdown within the dropdown box, you can try:

- First, adding a nested dropdown structure inside the `.hidden-text`
  div.
- Then, within your CSS, style the nested dropdown to be hidden by
  default and show when clicked.
- And finally, add an event listener using JavaScript to the nested
  dropdown to toggle its visibility